# Cannot import from or debug models.py

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've created 5 classes in a `models.py` inside my app `city`. I successfully created a db in postgres by importing each class inside the console accordingly. Next, I created a `jobs.py` script inside the `city` app so I can automatically scrape data using bs4 and populate/update a db accordingly.

The problem occurs when I try to import each class from `models.py` at the top of my `jobs.py` script:

`from city.models import restaurants, barbers, apartments, bars, parks`

Generates:

`'Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.'`

Any idea why I'm unable to import the classes from `models.py` into the `jobs.py` script?

I also created a python package `utils` inside my project. Inside `utils` is a `name_directory.py` script that I'm also unable to import into my `jobs.py` script.

Also, I just tried debugging my `models.py` file and it generated the same error!

Comment: What is not clear about the error message?

Comment: I don't know how or where to define DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE!

Comment: Your file might be imported before the settings file are loaded by django, did you added your app to the INSTALLED_APP in the global config.py ? Did you imported your job code from another part of the app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, can you read the manual, before ask?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage

if you settings of environment are correct:

```
import django
django.setup()

# after django.setup() you can start import models from you rdjango  app
```

Comment: This was helpful but incomplete. It led me to the solution [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AS01VoC9l5w)